# System.Data.SQlite for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, deployment, system.data.sqlite

The current distribution for System.Data.SQLite does not work with Visual Studio 2013 unless you deploy the VS2012 Update3 release pack (presumably) or just install (on a test machine like I did) the full version.

Does anyone know when the System.Data.SQLite team will release builds for Visual Studio 2013, both the precompiled static libraries that I would distribute to a customer and the full designer version that I would use?

The current release as of this post is 1.0.89.0, which does not include options for VS2013.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a build that natively supports VS2013.  Go to http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and search for "Visual Studio 2013". As of today the install is called sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.92.0.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not supported on VS 2013, but soon will be(Like most other libraries)

I believe they build every 2 weeks of the core project.

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q1

Comment: Thanks. Upon reading, I see: "1.0.89.0 - October 28, 2013." Visual Studio 2013 was out for a relatively a while by this date and no 2013 support. The pending change logs do not mention 2013, so it is not sure that the January 2014 build will include VS2013.

Comment: hmm ... only sqlite seems to build every month or so :)

Comment: It says it supports VS 2013 here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q4

Comment: mmmm not sure. I juste tried 3hours googling, installing, uninstalling, rebooting...no way to create any single data connections. SQLite driver in do not appear in my list of available drivers

Comment: It doesn't show up as a driver. Also, as of writing this, the source from the above site downloads, but won't compile on VS 2013 ultimate. It appears he/they use a generator to export the solution files/etc and is a right messy hole for code. Upon opening the project, 90% of the files are not "included" but if you include, you get duplicate errors, plus "mscorelib" shows as a bad ref prob.   v1.0.96.0