# System.Data.SQlite not showing in change data source of Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and it's up to date. I was in search of using a local database which doesn't require SQL Server to be installed on a client machine. I figured out that SQLite is the one that I should use, so I installed SQLite through NuGet. When I tried to create a data source from Server Explorer, I was expecting to see the System.Data.SQLite which was unfortunately not present.

All of the references and required files are included in my solution. I did all the steps, searched different forums and tried all but nothing worked. I also followed the steps that were present in Stack Overflow for the Visual Studio 2012 but none of them worked. What steps I should follow in order to use SQLite properly?

Comment: Check the last comment in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060222/system-data-sqlite-for-visual-studio-2013?rq=1

Comment: I used the 32 bit version of the sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.92.0.exe and the problem solved. Before that I was using the 64 bit version of it as my windows is 64 bit !. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where I installed the System.Data.SQLite packages from Nuget, but the 'System.Data.SQLite Database File' option would not be listed as a data source.

In order to fix this problem, I ran through some of the steps from [this blog post by Brecht Carlier](https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/sqlite-entityframework-6-tutorial/).  I fixed the issue by uninstalling the package, going to the [official SQLite downloads page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), searching for the `32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.5.1) Setup` executable, which is the one labeled:

> This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2013.

Then I ran the executable, re-installed the System.Data.SQLite package through NuGet, and rebuilt the project.  Everything seemed to work after that.

The problem seems to be that **even if you're on a 64-bit machine, you need to download the 32-bit version.**  Hope this helps.

Comment: "The problem seems to be that even if you're on a 64-bit machine, you need to download the 32-bit version" what solved  my problem.